# Given $z, w\in\mathbb{C}$ prove that $|z| = 1$ implies $|(z + w)/(1 + \overline{z}w)| = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification

I know I am supposed to write my process, but the thing is I have no clue.

I tried to rewrite $z$ as $a + bi$ and $w$ as $x + yi$ and try to rearrange the left side in a way I can get to the other, but no success.

Then I tried to solve like $|(z + w)/(1 +  \overline{z}w)| = 1$ iff $|z| = 1$ because i thought it would be easier to make $w$ "disapear" and end up with $|z| = 1$, but no success as well.

(i am not putting what i did, because it's all wrong and useless)

I hope you know and help me :(

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $|z|=1$, then $\bar z=1/z$. See if you can use this to rearrange the expression
$$\frac{z+w}{1+\bar zw}$$
into something more manageable.

Comment: Is not |z|^2 = 1, then z = 1/z̅? Should I square both sides?

Comment: @FernandoCavendish I don't understand what you mean. If $|z|^2\neq 1$, then $\bar z\neq 1/z$, but this isn't relevant here. All you need is that $|z|=1\implies \bar z=1/z$; then you can substitute in $1/z$ for $\bar z$ in your expression, and it will simplify nicely.

Comment: I mean z̅ * z = |z|^2. So if  z̅ * z  = 1, then z̅ = 1/z. How do I go from |z| = 1 to z̅ = 1/z?

Comment: @FernandoCavendish So, you know $z\bar z=|z|^2$. From this, if $|z|=1$, then $z\bar z=1$. This gives $z=1/\bar z$.

Comment: OHHH jesus i'm so stupid now it got it. sorry and thank you very much